# Python, Using regex to read a password

Tags: python, regex

I am aware that you can use the pwd module on python to extract passwd structures for use; however, my question is as such:

if I read into my program a line such as

```
blah1:tVNIsQ0yDrLxM:16009:0:99999:7:::
```

or

```
blah2:$6$WVsjYh8e$5r2wvIaeiFI6CCFRw6stfbah0Q.wrcKITdmEDCvG2cNC4fXkVbgRiOdeCdU.WeD1NIyzLh/sXycXQFEQcNWsv/:16009:0:99999:7:::
```

how would I read just the section that reads "tVNIsQ0yDrLxM"?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not that person, but your question violates several items on the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there's no extra colons in there, this should work:

```
password = hash.split(':')[1]
```

[split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: appreciated. thanks for the help.